# Can you lose messages in Apache camel between endpoints?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a camel route configured like this:

```
 <route id="route1" autoStartup="true">
    <from uri="response-jms:queue:MYQUEUE?concurrentConsumers=10" />
    <to uri="bean:processorOne?method=process" />
    <to uri="bean:processorTwo?method=process" />
 </route>
```

I think I sometimes have the case where processorTwo isn't executed on messages.  This happens only when there is heavy traffic.   Can Apache drop messages if processorTwo is slower than processorOne?  If so, what is the standard method of dealing with this issue?

Comment: It shouldn't drop the messages even if `processorTwo` is slower than `processorOne`. You could try pushing the output messages from `processorOne` to another queue and then consume the messages using `processorTwo` from that queue. This will give you a better control on how you would like your messages to be processed.

Comment: It shouldn't "lose" any messages in the sense that the messages just vanish from the route. The message always goes somewhere unless the container you're running camel in dies. If you have an exception occur in processorOne it would break out of the route. Can you check to make sure there aren't any error being thrown?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.   I know that processOne has completed successfully for the missing message.   If ProcessorTwo is slow,  how do the messgaes build up?   Camel must create some implicit queue or something right?   Is there a dead letter queue for the case that the implicit queue fills up?

Comment: Your route by default is single threaded. A new message won't be consumed in the route until the current message leaves the route (either by going through the whole route or if an error causes it to break out). If processorOne is taking too long, the route will simply wait for the message to complete before consuming more message from the jms route.

Comment: Thanks for replying David.   Does that mean if processTwo is slow, messages are not picked up by processOne until processTwo is ready to take another message?   There are 10 consumers so I'm guessing it's like there's 10 pairs of processOnes/processTwos?   When processTwo is done, processOne can pick up another message off the queue?

Comment: Your route "route1" won't pick up any new messages until it's current message has cleared the entire route. Meaning a message will have to finish both processorOne AND processorTwo successfully before route will pick up another message.

When you say there are "10 consumers" I'm assuming you have 10 instances of your route deployed. If one message is getting stuck in processorOne, that route is "locked" until the message finished. In the meantime, one of the other 9 instances of your route is free to consume any messages from the jms queue.